# Error in "The C++ Programming Language" Section "23.4.7 Friends"

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I have been trying to get the following code work from the book "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)" section "23.4.7 Friends" but could not succeed.

```
template<typename T> class Matrix;

template<typename T>
class Vector {
    T v[4];
public:
    friend Vector operator*<>(const Matrix<T>&, const Vector&); /* line 7 */
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
class Matrix {
    Vector<T> v[4];
public:
    friend Vector<T> operator*<>(const Matrix&, const Vector<T>&); /* line 14 */
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& m, const Vector<T>& v)
{
    Vector<T> r;
    // ... m.v[i] and v.v[i] for direct access to elements ...
    return r;
}
```

Here is a sample usage for the above API:

```
int main() {
    Matrix<int> lhs;
    Vector<int> rhs;
    Vector<int> r = lhs * rhs;

    return 0;
}
```

g++ with version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
```

gave the following output:

```
test.cpp:7: error: declaration of ‘operator*’ as non-function
test.cpp:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
test.cpp:14: error: declaration of ‘operator*’ as non-function
test.cpp:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

and clang with version:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

gave the following output:

```
test2.cpp:7:19: error: friends can only be classes or functions
    friend Vector operator*<>(const Matrix<T>&, const Vector&);
                  ^
test2.cpp:7:28: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    friend Vector operator*<>(const Matrix<T>&, const Vector&);
                           ^
                       ;
test2.cpp:14:22: error: friends can only be classes or functions
    friend Vector<T> operator*<>(const Matrix&, const Vector<T>&);
                     ^
test2.cpp:14:31: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    friend Vector<T> operator*<>(const Matrix&, const Vector<T>&);
                              ^
                              ;
4 errors generated.
```

The book says:

> The <> after the name of the firend function is needed to make clear
>   that the friend is a template function.

I could not spot the problem in the code, can you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug in the book.

The function template must already be visible at that point, otherwise [it cannot be instantiated to produce the overload you're trying to befriend](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e3a0d3169e113a4).

So, moving the operator definitions above that of `Vector` (which in itself requires that we provide a forward declaration) [solves the problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adca861130b8ba7d).